# Reference IMPORTRANGE() function stored in another cell/named-range?

Tags: google-sheets

To work more dynamic, I want to exchange my existing `IMPORTRANGE()` formulas in my sheet with my importrange-variables, where each unique `IMPORTRANGE()`function is stored in their own named-range, to make the code on my other sheet a little bit more flexible and clearer in case any import range changes. So I basically want to reference a formula stored in another cell/named-range. I found some solutions but nothing that deals with a `IMPORTRANGE()` function. I'm currently having that:

```
# Indexmatch with importrange
=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UTvlsienwl30slslielswpeowIUILEN/edit", "my_first_named_range"), MATCH(K65, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UTvlsielwieoeneIlswpeowIUILEN/edit", "my_second_named_range"), 0), 12)
```

**named range (single cell) / `import_ref_01`**

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UTvlsienwl30slslielswpeowIUILEN/edit", "my_first_named_range")
```

**named range (single cell) / `import_ref_02`**

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/UTvlsielwieoeneIlswpeowIUILEN/edit", "my_second_named_range")
```

**Expected result:**

```
=INDEX(import_ref_01, MATCH(K65, import_ref_02, 0), 12)
```

**EDITABLE SAMPLE SHEET WHERE DATA IS IMPORTED:**

[work_with_imported_data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g5zbkeYDTubEH6I9Vybf6-YiCmOq9lMTFoVxcB3jYog/edit?usp=sharing)

**EDITABLE SAMPLE SHEET OF THE SOURCE TABLE:**

[data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vKo77HGn89vCXDUuCqXlblfCT3exDtwtplXUHTAZ9-w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

You should surround your named ranges with double quotes `""` and use  `INDIRECT`.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("import_ref_01"), MATCH(K65, INDIRECT("import_ref_02"), 0), 12)
```

Comment: I actually tried to do that before without `""` around the named range and didn't work. Now tried your approach with `""` around the named range and didn't work either. So this is not working.

Comment: Please tell me which is which. 1. You have `Spread1` from where you import a range and you create a named range in `Spread2` named `import_ref_01`. You import a **different range** and name the second one `import_ref_02`. **OR** 2. You import the same range, give it 2 different name ranges and want to refer to different cells in them?

Comment: Yes sure, so I'm currently in `spreadsheet01` where I have `sheet1` with my index match function and `sheet2` with my data library, where I store the importrange-strings. One importrange-string imports data from `spreadsheet02`  `sheet01` and the other importrange-string from `spreadsheet02` `sheet02`. Everything you understood sounds right. To the named ranges, I think if I understood you right the first of your options is the case.

Comment: Works in my end. You probably import more than one columns. In such a case, it can still be achieved with similar formulas. Please share a test sheet for a custom made solution.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of columns that's right. Making a sheet will take me some time, as I sadly can't share the original one as the data is not public.

Comment: Hi, did @marikamitsos solution eventually worked for you? If so, could you please accept it so that other users with similar questions find it easily? If not, could you please describe a bit better the range you are getting from your ```IMPORTRANGE``` (like 4 rows and 3 columns etc)? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Since the OP is importing multiple columns this formula will not work (as mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599092/reference-importrange-function-stored-in-another-cell-named-range/61599700?noredirect=1#comment108970628_61599700)). If you are still interested in a solution, please create a question so I can answer it there. A dummy sheet would be necessary.

Comment: Hi all, thanks so far for your feedback. I now got the time to create a sample spreadsheet for you. I've included it at the end of the updated question. I hope that helps for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have something that might work for you. Here's a link to a tab on your sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g5zbkeYDTubEH6I9Vybf6-YiCmOq9lMTFoVxcB3jYog/edit#gid=941801062&range=C2

Formula that worked:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE(data_sample_IR1, data_sample_IR2), 
       MATCH( B2, IMPORTRANGE( data_sample_titles_IR1, data_sample_titles_IR2), 0),
       3)
```

where the named ranges are:

data_sample_IR1 = " ...your data sheet key... "

WITH the quote marks, and

data_sample_IR2 = A1:Q45

and the other two named ranges are the same, but for your titles range.

This required moving the "IMPORTRANGE" text out of the named range.

If you need the flexibity of sometimes using IMPORTRANGE, and sometimes not, you could perhaps handle that with an IF wrapper around it all.
Let me know if this helps.